# Adding NSOperation dependencies to operations already in an NSOperationQueue

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I want to implement some background network requests using an `NSOperationQueue`. I have a couple of different requests that would be added to the queue by different parts of the code, and one of these will run more regularly than the other.

I already implement this using GCD so I have blocks of code, therefore I was planning to simply use the `NSBlockOperation` method `blockOperationWithBlock:^{...}` and not create sub classes of `NSOperation`.

This problem is that I would like to create a dependency between the requests. If the queue already has an `NSBlockOperation` for requestA then I want to add a dependency to it when I create `NSBlockOperation` for requestB. This is trivial when creating the operations at the same time, but I can't find an easy way to determine what operations already exist in the queue.

`NSOperationQueue` has an `operations` property, so I can retrieve a list of the operations themselves, but how do I determine which operation is which? I don't see a name/description property that I can use.

The options I can think of are:

1. Subclass `NSOperation` to create custom objects for each request type, then use introspection on the objects retrieved from the `operations` property
2. Subclass `NSBlockOperation` and add a description property

Am I missing some other obvious way to do this?

Comment: Couldn't you just keep your `NSBlockOperation` object lying around in a manner that you can know which is which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an instance variable holding the most recent `requestA` operation.  Clear it out at the end of the `requestA` block.  E.g.

```
_requestA = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    // Normal requestA code here.
    // ...

    // Assuming you create all requestA and requestB instances on the main thread...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ _requestA = nil; });
}];
```

Then when you create a `requestB`, you can give it the latest `requestA` as a dependency, if there is still one to be used.

Comment: Thanks Rob, this is a good suggestion and I think it will do what I need it to do. I shall give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

You could use priorities.

`[NSBlockOperation setPriority:NSOperationQueuePriority]`

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html

Then when you enumerate through the operations you could check the priority levels and add them as a dependency or not. You may not even need to check them and just set the priority level of your operation appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the proper way would be to subclass either NSOperation or NSBlockOperation and in this subclass implement an `-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)object` method so you can compare the operations you find in the NSOperationQueue's operations property. That way you should be able to use the builtin `[operationA addDependency:operationB];`